# How to find a center of polygon?

Tags: c#, center, polygon

I have a polygon, one in three types: convex, non-convex, with holes) that include sa list of vertices (point x,y) and edges (start point, end point). Now I have to find one point to put a label within the polygon and is center of largest part. How do I do that?

Comment: @EddieB The C# tag doesn't clue you in? =)

Comment: @J.Steen facepalm I digress.

Comment: @EddieB We all have bad days. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to start from is IMO

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

At the end of the latter you find some links to implementations, maybe these are of help for you.